# Grant READ ONLY permissions to all tables in all databases

Tags: postgresql, permissions, postgresql-12

I created new role named "support" in my PostgreSQL. Now I need grant "READ ONLY" permissions for this role an ALL exists databases/tables. 
Also I need automatically granted same permissions on each DB that will created in future.

I unsuccessfully tried next queries for grant permissions in new databases (Can not select from new database tables ):

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE support GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO PUBLIC;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES to support;
```

Answer (score 0):

> ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES allows you to set the privileges that will be
>   applied to objects created in the future. (It does not affect
>   privileges assigned to already-existing objects.)

Comment: Actually it give permissions only in current database. It not works with new databases